# floor()/int() function implementaton

Tags: function, implementation

Does anyone have an idea how is the method/function `Int()` or `floor()` implemented?
What I am looking for a respective implementation as the following is for `abs()` function.

```
Int Abs (float x){
  if x > 0 
      return x;
   else
      return -x
}
```

I am struggling to find a solution for it without using the modulus operator.

Comment: an indication of why in the world you need this would be good.

Comment: @WinstonEwert maybe he wants to get rid of branching.

Comment: @kvantour, 7 years later I doubt he still wants to do whatever he was trying to do. Regardless, the question looks a lot like "how do I breathe without using up any oxygen"

Answer (score 27):

Seems to me like

```
floor(n) = n - (n % 1)
```

should do the trick.

Comment: This answer is great for flooring where a built-in floor function is not available, and it doubles as a practical explanation of what modulo does. Thank you!

Comment: This is perfect.  Do you have a similar implementation for `ceil()`?

Comment: Is this not failing for negative `n`? floor(-1.5) gives me (-1)

Comment: For those wanting a response to the comment about ceil, just look at what floor does. 
where (x) = 0.3 `0.3 - (0.3 % 1) = 0.3 - 0.3 = 0` so
for ceil, just first calculate the inverse of .3, which is 1 -.3, which is .7.

`ceil(x) = (1 - x) + (x % 1);`

Answer (score 6):

Using the [IEEE 754 binary floating point representation](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/91float/) one possible solution is:

```
float myFloor(float x)
{
  if (x == 0.0)
    return 0;

  union
  {
    float input;   // assumes sizeof(float) == sizeof(int)
    int   output;
  } data;

  data.input = x;

  // get the exponent 23~30 bit    
  int exp = data.output & (255 << 23);
  exp = exp >> 23;

  // get the mantissa 0~22 bit
  int man = data.output & ((1 << 23) - 1);

  int pow = exp - 127;
  int mulFactor = 1;

  int i = abs(pow);
  while (i--)
    mulFactor *= 2;

  unsigned long long denominator = 1 << 23;
  unsigned long long numerator = man + denominator;

  // most significant bit represents the sign of the number
  bool negative = (data.output >> 31) != 0;

  if (pow < 0)
    denominator *= mulFactor;
  else
    numerator *= mulFactor;

  float res = 0.0;
  while (numerator >= denominator) {
    res++;
    numerator -= denominator;
  }

  if (negative) {
    res = -res;
    if (numerator != 0)
      res -= 1;
  }

  return res;
}


int main(int /*argc*/, char **/*argv*/)
{
  cout << myFloor(-1234.01234) << " " << floor(-1234.01234) << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: How does this differ from [Michal's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6437076/774086), [Seronis's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26091248/774086) and [TheJubilex's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5123037/774086) answers?

Comment: @FaridNouriNeshat This answer may practically be the same as those others but shows how `int(value)` could be implemented using bit-level instructions. (This is the answer I would be looking for if I asked the question originally and I would be disappointed to get the others which seem obvious.)

Comment: Trying to figure out how INT works is what brought me here.  In relation to a situation where I wanted to run a particular formula through a solver to get some permutations on it, and found out that neither gauss brackets ⌊x⌋ nor modulo were options.  When I googled and saw this on stack overflow I assumed that it would be something along the lines of zkunov's answer, not those you mention.

Answer (score 4):

```
private static int fastFloor(double x) {
    int xi = (int)x;
    return x < xi ? xi - 1 : xi;
}
```

This is a method similar to Michal Crzardybons answer but it avoids a conditional branch and still handles negative numbers properly.

Comment: I guess you have a condition also

Comment: yes.  i didnt say it avoids all branches.  I said it avoids 'a' conditional branch.  His uses 2 branches. Mine uses 1.

Comment: This is invalid as fastFloor(-2) will return -3 instead of -2

Answer (score 2):

If result of type 'int' is enough, then here is a simple alternative:

```
int ifloor( float x )
{
    if (x >= 0)
    {
        return (int)x;
    }
    else
    {
        int y = (int)x;
        return ((float)y == x) ? y : y - 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int(x)   = x - x%1
floor(x) = int(x)-(x<0 && x%1!=0)
ceil(x)  = int(x)+(x>0 && x%1!=0)
round(x) = floor(x)+(x>0&&x%1>=0.5)+(x<0&&(1+x%1)%1>=0.5)
```

**note:** `round(x)` is not implemented as `floor(x+0.5)` as this will fail at `x=0.5-2^-54`

**note:** logical operations are assumed to convert to integer values 1 for true and 0 for false

---

Implementations are done so they match the domains defined in [`int(x)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/trunc), [`floor(x)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/floor), [`ceil(x)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/ceil) and [`round(x)`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_up)

Answer (score 0):

The best answer doesn't work for negative numbers so I've modified it:

```
floor(n) = n - (n % 1 >= 0 ? n%1: (1 + n % 1))
```

```
ceil(n) = -floor(-n)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>

int myfloor(int x) {
    if (x > 0)
        return x;
    else
        return x - 1;
}
int main() {
    double x = -5.9;
    std::cout<<myfloor(x);
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: I think your answer relies on automatic type conversion from float to int, right? I don't think your solution works for 0 (would return -1) and any negative numbers without decimals, i.e. -1.0 would return -2.0.