# Math.Floor overflow in delphi 5

Tags: delphi, integer-overflow, delphi-5, floor

I'm working on an old school Delphi 5 application and I've noticed something about the `Math.Floor` function.

I have an expression that I would like to evaluate the Floor of

[image: expression]

But when I calculate the floor

[image: Floor]

I end up with a value that is clearly not correct, presumably due to integer overflow.

I thought of using the modulo operator as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5122993/floor-int-function-implementaton), but it looks like mod isn't applicable for these operands.

There's got to be a way ...

Comment: Can you supply code to reproduce this, instead of screenshots.

Comment: The important code snippets are in the screenshots

Comment: Try evaluating `Math.Floor(2147558400.5)` 
I believe the problem is that the integer type has a limited size, I'm just not sure what I can do about it.

Comment: Okay, reproduced it. Yes math.Floor returns an integer, and your value is larger than MaxInt, so the standard function will never work.

Comment: It's easy enough to copy `Math.Floor` locally, and change Integer to Cardinal. Add code to handle the sign if you expect to have negatives

Comment: What do you intend to do with the output?

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it does indeed work for the test data I was using. Obviously if the data ever goes beyond the range of cardinals I will have the same problem ....

Comment: For your information the reason you get this value is because the doc Math.Floor says "The absolute value of X must be less than MaxInt." which is 2^32 = 2,147,483,647 and you are evaluating a value smaller than that.

Comment: As already asked by @David Heffernan: What do you intend? If you just what to truncate the fractional part, just use the `int` function instead of `floor`, but remember that the result remains a floating point number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to David A's suggestion:

```
function CardinalFloor(X: Extended): Cardinal;
begin
  Assert(X>=0);
  Result := Cardinal(Trunc(X));
end;
```

is one possible work around

Comment: What if X is negative?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Good point to bring up here. I was expecting `if Frac(X) <0 then Dec(Result)` to handle that. Although I will also be happy with a solution that does not handle negative values.

Comment: Handle it in what way. Can't fit negative value in unsigned type. Very hard to help if you want tell us what you are actually doing.

Comment: Actually, I think you are right. It's probably better to get rid of that part of the code.

Comment: What I'm getting at is that it's hard to know what to suggest to you without knowing what your inputs are and what you plan to do with the output.

Comment: In my case, the output of this function will be used as the index into a large array. I suppose It's possible that an array could be bigger than limit of the cardinal type.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102433/discussion-between-sav-and-david-heffernan).

Comment: You can't have an array that large in D5. So the whole question is pointless. This is why you should have presented the motivation. Hence my original comment to the question.

Comment: hmm ... well if arrays can't be any larger than that, perhaps I have the answer to my question as I have posed it

Comment: I wouldn't say so. There are many things you might do. You might use the `int` intrinsic and keep a floating point value. You might use a 64 bit integer. It all depends on the underlying goal which was not provided. Anyway, you don't seem to want to explore any of that. So let's just leave it.